# Copy type signature from another function

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Imagine I have a set of functions like below. `foo` has a lot of arguments of various types, and `bar` passes all its arguments to that other function. Is there any way to make mypy understand that `bar` has the same type as `foo` without explicitly copying the whole argument list?

```py
def foo(a: int, b: float, c: str, d: bool, *e: str, f: str = "a", g: str = "b") -> str:
    ...

def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    val = foo(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
    return val
```

Comment: This is covered in [PEP-612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) (`ParamSpec`). Support for mypy is still outstanding (see [mypy#8645](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645)).

Comment: @DanielleMadeley [#8645](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645) as been closed. I couldn't figure out how to apply this to the use case in this question. Can you explain?

Comment: I could have sworn there was an example in the PEP.  It's not that different to the accepted answer really. You need to make yourself an identity decorator that goes `Callable[P, T] -> Callable[P, T]` where `P = ParamSpec('P'); T = TypeVar('T')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968447/python-typing-copy-kwargs-from-one-function-to-another has an example answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's been a lot of discussion about adding this feature [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270). For the straightforward case of passing all arguments you can use the recipe from [this comment](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270#issuecomment-555966301):

```py
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

class copy_signature(Generic[F]):
    def __init__(self, target: F) -> None: ...
    def __call__(self, wrapped: Callable[..., Any]) -> F: ...

def f(x: bool, *extra: int) -> str: ...

@copy_signature(f)
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

reveal_type(test)  # Revealed type is 'def (x: bool, *extra: int) -> str'
```

Comment: This works, with a few drawbacks: `--strict` still reports that the parameters are untyped, and the return type of `__init__` is `None`, so copying that doesn't quite work.

Comment: If you could add a comment about that to the issue, that'd be great.