# Python Typing: Copy `**kwargs` from one function to another

Tags: python, python-typing

It is common pattern in Python extend or wrap functions and use `**kwargs` to pass all keyword arguments to the extended function.

i.e. take

```py
class A:
    def bar(self, *, a: int, b: str, c: float) -> str:
       return f"{a}_{b}_{c}"
   

class B(A):
    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        return f"NEW_{super().bar(**kwargs)}"


def base_function(*, a: int, b: str, c: float) -> str:
    return f"{a}_{b}_{c}"


def extension(**kwargs) -> str:
    return f"NEW_{base_function(**kwargs)}"
```

Now calling `extension(not_existing="a")` or `B().bar(not_existing="a")` would lead to a `TypeError`, that could be detected by static type checkers.

How can I annotate my `extension` or `B.bar` in order to detect this problem before I run my code?

This annotation would be also helpful for IDE's to give me the correct suggestions for `extension` or `B.bar`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

[PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612) introduced the `ParamSpec` (see [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec)) Type.

We can exploit this to generate a decorator that tells our type checker, that the decorated functions has the same arguments as the given function:

```py
from typing import (
   Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast, Any, Type, Literal,
)

# Define some specification, see documentation
P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

# For a help about decorator with parameters see 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters
def copy_kwargs(
    kwargs_call: Callable[P, Any]
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    """Decorator does nothing but returning the casted original function"""

    def return_func(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        return cast(Callable[P, T], func)

    return return_func
```

This will define a decorator than can be used to copy the complete [ParameterSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) definition to our new function, keeping it's return value.

Let's test it (see also [MyPy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.2.0&python=3.10&gist=2d97841e3534b140c24913b3596092d0))

```py
# Our test function for kwargs
def source_func(foo: str, bar: int, default: bool = True) -> str:
    if not default:
        return "Not Default!"
    return f"{foo}_{bar}"

@copy_kwargs(source_func)
def kwargs_test(**kwargs) -> float:
    print(source_func(**kwargs))
    return 1.2

# define some expected return values
okay: float
broken_kwargs: float
broken_return: str

okay = kwargs_test(foo="a", bar=1)
broken_kwargs = kwargs_test(foo=1, bar="2")
broken_return = kwargs_test(foo="a", bar=1)
```

This works as expected with [pyre 1.1.310](https://pyre-check.org/), [mypy 1.2.0](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and PyCharm 2023.1.1.
All three will complain about about the broken kwargs and broken return value.
Only PyCharm has troubles to detect the `default` argument, [as PEP 612 support is not yet fully implemented](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51766/Meta-PEP-612-Parameter-Specification-Variables-support-improvements).

#### ⚠️ Limitations

Still we need to by very careful how to apply this function.
Assume the following call

```py
runtime_error = kwargs_test("a", 1)
```

Will lead the runtime error “*kwargs_test1() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given*” without any type checker complaining.

So if you copy `**kwargs` like this, ensure that you put all positional arguments into your function.
The function in which the parameters are defined should use [keyword only arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/).

So a best practise `source_func` would look like this:

```
def source_func(*, foo: str, bar: int, default: bool = True) -> str:
    if not default:
        return "Not Default!"
    return f"{foo}_{bar}"
```

But as this is probably often used on library functions, we not always have control about the `source_func`, so keep this problem in mind!

You also could add `*args` to your target function to prevent this problem:

```py
# Our test function for args and kwargs
def source_func_a(
  a: Literal["a"], b: Literal["b"], c: Literal["c"], d: Literal["d"], default: bool =True
) -> str:
    if not default:
        return "Not Default!"
    return f"{a}_{b}_{c};{d}"



@copy_kwargs(source_func_a)
def args_test(a: Literal["a"], *args, c: Literal["c"], **kwargs) -> float:
    kwargs["c"] = c
    # Note the correct types of source_func are not checked for kwargs and args,
    # if args_test doesn't define them (at least for mypy)
    print(source_func(a, *args, **kwargs))
    return 1.2

# define some expected return values
okay_args: float
okay_kwargs: float
broken_kwargs: float
broken_args: float

okay_args = args_test("a", "b", "c", "d")
okay_kwargs = args_test(a="a", b="b", c="c", d="d")
borken_args = args_test("not", "not", "not", "not")
broken_kwargs = args_test(a="not", b="not", c="not", d="not")
```

#### History of the PEP 612 Introduction for MyPy and PyCharm

MyPy and PyCharm had issues using `ParamSpec` when creating this answer. The issues seems to be resolved but the links are kept as historical reference:

- MyPy [merged a first implementation for ParamSpec](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/11847) on 7th April 2022
- According to [the related typedshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/4827) Issue, PyCharm should support `ParamSpec` but did not correctly detect the copied `**kwargs` but complained that `okay = kwargs_test(foo="a", bar=1)` would have invalid arguments. (Fixed now)
- Mypy:  [Allow using TypedDict for more precise typing of **kwds](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4441)
- Mypy: [PEP 612 tracking issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645)
- Pyright [Prototype support for typed **kwargs](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3002)

#### Using Concatenate

If you want to copy the kwargs but also want to allow additional parameters you need to adopt kwargs with [Concanate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate):

```py
from typing import Concatenate

def copy_kwargs_with_int(
    kwargs_call: Callable[P, Any]
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., T]], Callable[Concatenate[int, P], T]]:
    """Decorator does nothing but returning the casted original function"""

    def return_func(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[Concatenate[int, P], T]:
        return cast(Callable[Concatenate[int, P], T], func)

    return return_func

@copy_kwargs_with_int(source_func)
def something(first: int, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
    print(f"Yeah {first}")
    return str(source_func(*args, **kwargs))

something("a", "string", 3) # error: Argument 1 to "something" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
okay_call: str
okay_call = something(3, "string", 3) # okay
```

See [MyPy Play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.2.0&python=3.10&gist=d0956f53649322c51e5b2a3b00013dbf) for details.

Note: Currently you need to define the a decorator for each variable you want to add and due to the nature of Concanate they can also just be added as args in front.

Comment: It would be nice to see this ability incorporated into functools as a capability of update_wrapper

Comment: Indeed. But maybe even with more functionality. I.e. automatically detecting the return value, and allowing to combine the arguments of multiple functions using [Concatenate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate)
Also maybe this should go into tpying and not functools? But yeah probably worth a PEP request IMHO.

Comment: On 22-23 July 2023 at the PyCon Europe in Prague I would like to discuss this (together  with others Issues) and maybe formulate a PEP.
Maybe someone here is interested and would like [to join the sprint](https://ep2023.europython.eu/sprints#typing-peps).

Comment: +1, great analysis. I'm currently implementing a function which passes all args and kwargs to another function, but the "parent" function has one extra input parameter (it's a classmethod, so it's `def method(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. Would anyone have a suggestion for how it can copy the args and kwargs of a function but "prepend" the `cls` argument?

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnússon added an Concanate example.

Comment: Thanks @Kound, how would you add as args in front? If I try to add an arg "prepend: Any" to `copy_kwargs_with_int`, and then add `prepend=int` in the decorator, I get a ` Name "prepend" is not defined  [name-defined]`. The issue seems to be that the input variable is not in the scope of the function return declaration. Is there any elegant solution here?

Comment: Please read the linked [Concanate Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate). If you have troubles please open a new question. @SteinnHauserMagnússon (you can ping me there)

Answer (score 3):

Based on @kound answer.

To remain DRY, we can do the same without re-declaring return type. Type variable `T` will be deduced later (not when `copy_kwargs` is called, but when its returned function is), but it doesn't affect further type checking.

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast, Any

# Our test function
def source_func(*, foo: str, bar: int) -> str:
    return f"{foo}_{bar}"

# Define some specification, see documentation
P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

# For a help about decorator with parameters see 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters
def copy_kwargs(kwargs_call: Callable[P, Any]) -> Callable[[Callable[..., T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    """Decorator does nothing but returning the casted original function"""
    def return_func(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        return cast(Callable[P, T], func)

    return return_func


@copy_kwargs(source_func)
def kwargs_test(**kwargs) -> float:
    print(source_func(**kwargs))
    return 1.2

reveal_type(kwargs_test(foo="a", bar=1))
reveal_type(kwargs_test(foo=1, bar="2"))
```

And here's [mypy playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b1e178b01079b765f158257923b56f16) to look at this in action.

Comment: Nice that is works with the up to date MyPy. But it struggles with `PyRe`: `src/kwargs_dry.py:12:50 Invalid type variable [34]: The type variable 'Variable[T]' isn't present in the function's parameters.`  (pyre 0.9.11)

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's interesting to know. I'll file a report maybe, because here the type variable is actually bound (within another `Callable`), so it's a bug in `PyRe`.

Comment: Can we create a decorator to append kwargs to any function?  for example `kwargs_test(a:int, **kwargs)` and `kwargs_test2(a:str, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Yes it can. Have a look at [Concatenate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate).

Comment: Btw. I updated the answer above to reflect the current type check situation and also made my function DRY thanks to this example here.