# How to type a Python function the same way as another function?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pyright

For writing a wrapper around an existing function, I want to that wrapper to have the same, or very similar, type.

For example:

```py
import os

def my_open(*args, **kwargs):
    return os.open(*args, **kwargs)
```

Tye type signature for `os.open()` is complex and may change over time as its functionality and typings evolve, so I do not want to copy-paste the type signature of `os.open()` into my code. Instead, I want to *infer* the type for `my_open()`, so that it "copies" the type of `os.open()`'s parameters and return values.

`my_open()` shall have the same type as the wrapped function `os.open()`.

---

I would like to do the same thing with a decorated function:

```py
@contextmanager
def scoped_open(*args, **kwargs):
  """Like `os.open`, but as a `contextmanager` yielding the FD.
  """
  fd = os.open(*args, **kwargs)
  try:
    yield fd
  finally:
    os.close(fd)
```

Here, the inferred function arguments of `scoped_open()` shall be the same ones as `os.open()`, but the return type shall be a `Generator` of the *inferred* return type of `os.open()` (currently `int`, but again I do not wish to copy-paste that `int`).

---

I read some things about [PEP 612](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) here:

- [Python Typing: Copy `**kwargs` from one function to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968447/python-typing-copy-kwargs-from-one-function-to-another)
- [Python 3 type hinting for decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060133/python-3-type-hinting-for-decorator/68290080#68290080)

These seem related, but the examples given there still always copy-paste at least some part of the types.

**How can this be done in `pyright`/`mypy`/general?**

Comment: Your specific case - use [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) instead? There is no way to express "signature same as of some_function", unless `some_function` is passed as a parameter or decorated - in such case `ParamSpec`+`TypeVar` can preserve at least some typing of that function.

Comment: @STerliakov [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) does not work in this case, because that only works for `.close()` while `os.open()` returns a plain `int` FD on which `os.close()` needs to be called. So it works for Python's normal `open()`, but not `os.open()`. [`os.fdopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen) can help with that, but only for file FDs, not directory FDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass [the function you want to copy the signature of] into [a decorator factory] which produces a no-op decorator that affects the typing API of the decorated function.

The following example can be checked on [pyright-play.net](https://pyright-play.net/?code=MQAgDgngTglg5gCwC4C4QGcmwMZIFB7BEgCSAtmADYCmZ1AdkgIZIwD29IRwBAZlGzIgA%2BsN4BXJOKjVRIGBTZQkIJvXptmrDujwKwSlUghgY9OMOoAPJA3Tt66VU-x7eIJADoAKgE0ACgCiwgDCABKBIQDSJAByAOIoeCAp8orKINhslDS4DuieTABG2M6ZVgQAJtTuAO4wSAj%2BTFBMdLZQAIL0lQBK1FJQ9N4m1OgA8rwA2gBiaNhWniFMOcU0U56bADQent0QALoHABS8aDM7APQAlCAAtAB85UsrlGvUU7MHOzMHScmpABEwIBKWWYEG1A8CCh1iYuA8oxAbHcAANeKido0GOAZLYetCWNCodUsq1bJUQBJ6HkOPInCjoTBdKkQHCEcYwNRPKCQMDAQRWXjpJw3mQipUmCI0MIqjUQPVGs1Wu1qFARlyJtMAFTa-w7XonM7PZarIrrfW7fbfEA3e5PBYvM3rKaO01vc0fS2Gm1u17vKbeo7-Vn83ngyHE8AtNoDNUuJGM9GY4mcMB4hiUxpE7EgUlKFjUSnU2n0ADkLNSYBjqqgThaUMZjWZiK5PN5yYrIGFQ1bUJb8A0MkqOzUWZheeoZMLxfENO05acPc4nP7TnTYzVADcizzQyDecuQGKJVLhDKCIRiN4xkgnNwCPpDMjdPxBJkOLYbJQYEU0gYMiyRhrCQMg1CYOA1UvAABRUmhrOMuh6fpBmGUYtWONgCjYLl6GuPBqncMgIGEHCGGObUWjgdA0C8fYdl1ABrWoqJoq16AgW5HnYiAkiFAYRRfTwyPoCjWIY7VmNY-CCCYNBMCgEAAF4QGI0jcOOABGHYACYdgAZhkvBoKAr9QPAyCoGMuDlVjDoNTGSZMOw3D8MIjAsi5Sp1PIyioGo2i9g4iSpP8ti6I4riHUWeIGDVFglCmMwkB2WIOGoVL0r%2BXleEpFSsOEjS-OokKWLC-DWSwXjeVZCAYGoShi0qHKzFearWVZArsEoLDqFOSojLgjyyO8kStN0gzbiYes%2BKrab0CAA) (requires Python >= 3.12, as it uses syntax from [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/)).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

def withParameterAndReturnTypesOf[F: cx.Callable[..., t.Any]](f: F, /) -> cx.Callable[[F], F]:

    """
    Capture the exact type of `f`, then pretend that the decorated function is of this
    exact type.
    """

    return lambda _: _

def withParameterTypesOf[**P, R](f: cx.Callable[P, t.Any], /) -> cx.Callable[[cx.Callable[P, R]], cx.Callable[P, R]]:

    """
    Capture the parameters type of `f`, then pretend that the decorated function's
    parameters are of this type.

    `f`'s return type is ignored, and the decorated function's return type is preserved.
    """

    return lambda _: _
```

```py
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@withParameterAndReturnTypesOf(os.open)
def my_open(*args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> t.Any:
    return os.open(*args, **kwargs)

@contextmanager
@withParameterTypesOf(os.open)
def scoped_open(*args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> cx.Generator[int, None, None]:
    fd = os.open(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield fd
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
```

```
Expression of type "int" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
  "int" is incompatible with "str"  (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
    vvvvvv   vvvvvvv
>>> a: str = my_open(1, 2)
                     ^
Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "path" of type "StrOrBytesPath" in function "open"
  Type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to type "StrOrBytesPath"
    "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "str"
    "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "bytes"
    "Literal[1]" is incompatible with protocol "PathLike[str]"
      "__fspath__" is not present
    "Literal[1]" is incompatible with protocol "PathLike[bytes]"
      "__fspath__" is not present  (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
                     v
>>> with scoped_open(1, 2) as a: pass
         ^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^
Expression of type "int" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
  "int" is incompatible with "str"  (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Comment: I wish I haven't lost that battle against pep695 syntax-backed typevars and paramspec, typed python is getting further and futher from readability:(

Comment: @STerliakov ISN”T IT BEAUTIFUL???

Comment: No!!! After all, it makes functions look as if this type has some runtime implication, like generics in Rust where `.parse::<T>` parses a string into type T if the necessary trait is implemented. And hey, function signature are already the longest and most wrapped lines, type param bounds just make them insanely long. I saw this pep too late, so my objections just got lost in the discussion:(

Comment: @dROOOze Thank you! Is there a fallback which doesn't use the new typing syntax yet, that works for Python 3.10?

Comment: @nh2 They're simply `TypeVar`s and `ParamSpec`s. Make explicit assignments at the top of your module (`F = typing.TypeVar("F", bound=collections.abc.Callable[..., typing.Any])`, `P = typing.ParamSpec("P")`, `R = typing.TypeVar("R")`), then remove the square bracket item from after the function name. See [summary examples](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#summary-examples).