# Type inference across functions / reuse type hints

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have one function within an external library that has a complicated type hint ("inner"). In my code, I have another function ("outer") calling this function. One of the paramters of this function will be passed on to the hinted function. I would like to have mypy typecheck the parameter. How can I achieve this without copying the complicated type hint?

A [minimal example](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=cfb5d87871ccc7cebc42f2b928a84a68:) would be

```py
def inner(x: int) -> None:
    ...

def outer(x, y: str) -> None:
    """function that needs a typehint for x"""
    inner(x)

# This should throw an error
outer(x="a", y="a")
```

So I am looking for a way to define a TypeAlias based in the types of a parameter of an external inner function (which I cannot edit) without copying the type hints (and updating them if the inner functions type hints change)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502027/infer-return-type-annotation-from-other-functions-annotation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375881/how-to-type-a-python-function-the-same-way-as-another-function - I don't have time right now to further investigate whether one of them matches your situation.

Comment: The only correct thing to do is to specify the type on every function. Type hints are not there just for mypy, they are there for people. Do you expect other deveopers to have to read what your function is calling and what those functions are calling, just to find out which argument to send to the function?

Comment: @zvone maybe it would also be more useful for people to know that `x` is "whatever inner needs" rather than what concrete type it is.

Comment: @mkrieger1 If `inner` was a decorated function or a callable passed as argument, then yes, but if `inner` is just the implementation detail of `outer`, as it here is, then I disagree. `outer` needs to specify its interface explicitly.

Comment: One example are the pytorch indexer types:
Say, x is used to index in a torch.Tensor. So there will be an TypeAlias "TensorIndexer". But the fact that TensorIndexer is
"SupportsIndex | bool | int | slice | EllipsisType | Tensor | _NestedSequence[bool | int | slice | EllipsisType | Tensor | None] | tuple[SupportsIndex | bool | int | slice | EllipsisType | Tensor | _NestedSequence[bool | int | slice | EllipsisType | Tensor | None] | None, ...] | None" is an implementation detail that no human will ever parse.. 
It would be nice to just have mypy understand what it can be..

Comment: In that example, you could just write `x: TensorIndexer`, couldn't you?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear : I would like to define the alias TensorIndexer as 'whatever can be used to index into a tensor', instead of writing the full definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TypeAlias` to assign the type to a variable, then reuse it in both functions:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

X: TypeAlias = int
def inner(x: X) -> None:
    ...

def outer(x: X, y: str) -> None:
    """function that needs a typehint for x"""
    inner(x)

# This should throw an error
outer(x="a", y="a")
```

Edit: Apologies, I've just noticed the comment about it being an external library - you could monkey patch it to expose the Alias as a separate variable.

Comment: I think this solution applies also to external libraries. Except, in that case either the external library already defines the alias (the preferable case), or you define the alias only for your code and you make sure it matches whatever the library expects.